# Evaluating Performance of Spark on bare-metal against container

Tags: performance-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the performance of Spark running on bare-metal against one that runs in a container. I am trying to evaluate metrics like ***response time***, **CPU usage**, **memory usage**, **additional-resource-requirements** etc.

I want to know whether there exist standard sizable SparkJobs written to create enough load to test its performance (in the sense of research environments) out there.

Also, what are the standard and appropriate methods to measure the above metrics? Is it via simple terminal tools like ***top*** or ***MAC Activity-monitor*** to see how much memory and CPU it's consuming? And hardcoding calculations of timing differences to measure response-time etc.

Or are there standard ways of doing this?

Shabir

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/databricks/spark-perf? But, why do you think there would be a performance difference? Containers share the kernel with the host OS, so there isn't much of a difference between a process running on the host and the same program running in a container.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - Thanks for the link. Well true that there isn't **much** difference. But still, there is a difference. Need to evaluate it in order to verify how much of a throughput loss to expect when containerizing applications similar to Spark.